# Placing programming Q&A/recipe links in code comments

Tags: coding-style, comments

Quick question: I've started placing StackOverflow Q&A and recipe links in my code comments to remind me of where I found certain tricks.

Should I be doing this, or should I be working to translate the Q&A/recipe into more permanent (but redundant) comments?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think placing Q & A and recipe links in your code comments is a good idea at all. The main reason is that you are now maintaining a knowledge base in comments inside of your code. There isn't an easy way to reference this material. I would recommend keeping a separate document or wiki with the links and Q & A, if you want context, copy a sample of code into the document / wiki. I recommend a wiki if you are able to set this up because you can link around inside the wiki as well as linking out to external sites.